# Migrate Google Analytics Embed API to GA4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a dashboard based on the Google Analytics Embed API (javaScript library) to present charts inside my platform with Analytics UA results from my website. Basically, I was reading properties like this:

```
var report2 = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query: {
        ids: Dashboard.getIds(),
        metrics: 'ga:sessions',
        dimensions: 'ga:date',
        'start-date': Dashboard.getReportDateStart(),
        'end-date': Dashboard.getReportDateEnd(),
        filters: 'ga:sessionsPerUser==1'
    }
});

report2.on('success', function (response) {

    $("#metric-users-unique").text(response.totalsForAllResults["ga:sessions"]);
    $("#metric-sessions-unique").text(response.totalsForAllResults["ga:sessions"]);
});

report2.execute();
```

But now the only information I find from Google is "This API does not support Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties." and I have searched in Google's information but I can't find anything regarding the possibility to migrate this code to read from GA4.

Comment: Hi, thanks but my issue is not switching from UA to GA4 but switching the API so I can read the analytics values from GA4.

Answer (score 4):

The [Google Analytics Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1) only works with UA analytics it will not work with GA4.

My understanding from the team is there is currently no plans to port Google Analytics Embed API to GA4.  My last inquiry was in June

There is no way of porting it short of rewriting it yourself.

Comment: Hi @Linda, that's what I was afraid off, and do you know if there is any other way to read the metrics values of GA4 from javascript? Thanks.

Comment: I know there is a library for node.js but you would have to include the graphs yourself.   I dont think there is a javascript library for the data api yet.

Comment: Thanks @Linda, I will keep my searching for a solution :)

Comment: Let me know if you find one I have a had a few clients ask me to make one but havent had time.

Comment: sure I can share with you my findings ;)

Comment: @Patrick adding a bounty probably wont help.  I am a google developer expert for Google analytics I have direct contact to the GA team.  If there was an option for GA4 I would know about it.   I am freelance contact me if you are really interested in having one built.

Comment: Thank You, let me check first if I can't find any other way.